# React router is not working. It is showing nothing but a blank screen

Tags: reactjs, router, react-dom, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to make a simple react-router. But it's not even working. If I don't include the `<Routes>` tag the page is blank. After including the `<Routes>` tag it is also not working. Please take a look.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Nav';
import About from './About';
import Shop from './Shop';
import{ BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes }from 'react-router-dom';

function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <main>
        <Nav/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/shop" component={Shop}/>
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </Router> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Edit**: I am using the latest version (`6.3.0`) of `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing syntax for React Router v5 and v6. `<Routes>` tag is used in v6, but `component` field in `<Route>` is used in v5. You should be using v6 as it's the latest release, so you have to change `component` to `element`. You also can't have multiple `<Routes>` side by side.

[The documentation has a working example at the very top](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview), I suggest you start with that and modify according to your needs. Then if something breaks you can go back and see what you have done wrong.

Comment: yeah thanks! I figured to make it work.